# How can I get ExternalIdentity after all the login process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 and I can successfully login using Google.

I want to have access to the user external identity claims after the login process. I want in a view to access, for example, the claim "picture" from the user. However if I try to run this code it always return null. (except in the login process - auto generated code for mvc template)

[image: external info is null]

Is there a way for me to have access to the **external** identity claims? (after the login process)

Comment: `AuthenticationManager` = `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found how the identity is created. Basically the `ExternalSignInAsync` makes an internal call to `SignInAsync` which makes a call to `CreateUserIdentityAsync`.

I found a class `ApplicationSignInManager` in the `IdentityConfig` file and then I changed the `CreateUserIdentityAsync` method to:

```
public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var externalIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var localIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);

    foreach (var item in externalIdentity.Claims)
    {
        if (!localIdentity.HasClaim(o => o.Type == item.Type))
            localIdentity.AddClaim(item);
    }

    return localIdentity;
}
```

So every time I sign in I am going to have my claims + external claims in the loggedin user. From a view I can call:

```
@HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .Authentication.User.FindFirst("urn:google:picture").Value
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the auth token and then use that to query the login provider's API for the information you need. Storing it is easy enough:

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
const string XmlSchemaString = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string";

...

var googlePlusOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "yourclientid",
    ClientSecret = "yourclientsecret",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:googleplus:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Google"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googlePlusOptions);
```

Then, after you create the new user in `ExternalLoginCallback` or `ExternalLoginConfirm`:

```
await SaveAccessToken(user, identity);
```

With the following definition for `SaveAccessToken` (just put it with the other helper methods in the controller):

```
private async Task SaveAccessToken(User user, ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    var userclaims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);

    foreach (var at in (
        from claims in identity.Claims
        where claims.Type.EndsWith("access_token")
        select new Claim(claims.Type, claims.Value, claims.ValueType, claims.Issuer)))
    {
        if (!userclaims.Contains(at))
        {
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, at);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you'll have the access token to use later whenever you need it. So, for Google, to get the profile photo, you'd just send a request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=[token]`, where `[token]` is the value of the claim you saved.

Comment: During `ExternalLoginCallback` the `AuthenticationManager.User` doesn't contain the local identity yet... How can I get the User to add claims to it? http://imgur.com/hWF14fy

Comment: `var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login).WithCurrentCulture();` but i don't think that it is optimized.