# Map IdentityServer 4 claims to .NET MVC 4 client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

during this week i'm trying to get my client connected to my IdentityServer 4.

On the IdentityServer i've implemented the IProfileService to set some static claims on a user.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await _userClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        var claims = principal.Claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;

        var claims2 = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("role", "JustSpend.Employee"),
            new Claim("role", "JustSpend.Administrator"),
            new Claim("fullName", string.Format("{0} {1}", user.FirstName, user.LastName)),
            new Claim("canAccess", "JustSpend"),
            new Claim("canAccess", "APRA"),
            new Claim("canAccess", "SFVO")
        };

        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims2);
    }
```

At the MVC 4 client side I have the following configuration:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "NIC Identity",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server
            ClientId = "JSpend",
            ResponseType = "id_token code",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57895/signin-oidc", //URL of website
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:57895/",
            Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name", RoleClaimType = "role" },
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000");
                    var doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();


                    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        doc.TokenEndpoint,
                        "JSpend",
                        "secret");

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(doc.UserInfoEndpoint);

                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                    // create new identity
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    //id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));


                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }

                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

The claims were retreived all fine in the userInfoResponse. After the user have signed in, he is redirected to the AccountController (ExternalLoginCallback). But the claims are not mapped on the User in the controller at all.
ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Who can help me out? I'm looking for a solution the whole week, and if I Google, all the searchresults are turned purple (as visited)...

Comment: I've even tried to play arround with:
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"role", System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role},
            };

If I use this, the loginInfo in the externalLoginCallback method is null.

Comment: I found it, thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856300/how-can-i-get-externalidentity-after-all-the-login-process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856300/how-can-i-get-externalidentity-after-all-the-login-process#answer-25858190